# arrange fields of the form using bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3, form-fields

I am using Bootstrap3 in my project. I have enclosed my form in a jumbotron.
Here is how my form looks (not good looking as of now):
[image]

I tried to make it better. but it is getting worse. I want all the fields to be in one-line and
the submit button centered below them. I have no idea how to do it. I am very new using Bootstrap3.

Here is my html code:

```
<form  action="" id="id-exampleForm" class="form-inline" method="post" >
    <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='1bfhNFINdeJVpSNBBQd0X7zLWLVwm1bB' />
    <div id="div_id_price_order" class="form-group">
        <label for="id_price_order_0" class="control-label col-lg-2 requiredField">
            price order
            <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
        </label>
        <div class="controls col-lg-12">
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="price_order" id="id_price_order_1" value="lowest_price" >lowest</label>
            <label class="radio">
                <input type="radio" name="price_order" id="id_price_order_2" value="highest_price" >highest</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="div_id_newest_entry" class="checkbox">
            <div class="controls col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-12">
                <label for="id_newest_entry" class=" requiredField">
                    <input class="checkboxinput checkbox" id="id_newest_entry" name="newest_entry" type="checkbox" />
                    latest date
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div id="div_id_latest_year" class="checkbox">
            <div class="controls col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-12">
                <label for="id_latest_year" class=" requiredField">
                    <input class="checkboxinput checkbox" id="id_latest_year" name="latest_year" type="checkbox" />
                    latest year
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary button white" id="submit-id-submit" />
</form>
```

EDIT:

I want something like this: I have edited this on powerpoint. so it does not look very good.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT AFTER COMMENT

Please see the fiddle for an inline form in a Jumbotron with the button in-line (not below centered), and fieldset.

Note : that I changed the vertical alignment of the checkbox and radio + add some right margin, and an extra small button. The form will go as block if the screen is extra-small as a bootstrap behavior.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8KHF/)

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<form class="form-inline">
    <fieldset class="radiogroup"> 
        <legend>Sorting Criteria</legend> 
        <label for="id_price_order_0">
            price order
            <span class="asteriskField">*</span>
        </label>
        <label class="radio" for="id_price_order_1">
            lowest
            <input type="radio" checked="checked" id="id_price_order_1" />
        </label>
        <label class="radio" for="id_price_order_2">
            highest
            <input type="radio" id="id_price_order_2" />
        </label>
        <label for="id_newest_entry" class="requiredField checkbox">
            latest date
            <input id="id_newest_entry"  type="checkbox" />
        </label>
        <label for="id_latest_year" class="requiredField checkbox">
            latest year
            <input  id="id_latest_year"  type="checkbox" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"  />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I noticed there is a large spacing between each of the fields. I also want the submit button in-line with fields and for radio-buttons, I want to have fieldset/legend as shown here http://html.cita.illinois.edu/nav/form/radio/index.php?example=6. All in-line in a jumbotron container

Comment: @yaonn: thank you. I see a couple of issues. one is I am able to select both radio button at the same time, which should not happen. Other is I want fieldset only for radio buttons, i.e price order label around lowest and highest. I have a picture posted above.

Comment: I corrected the mono-selection on the radio buttons, you just have to add a common name property to the radios. I took off the fieldset. The fieldset tag is not right for your purpose. The screenshot you provide is a classic fieldset and then you say "I want that but like that", a bit confusing, can you provide a screenshot of what you want, please.
http://jsfiddle.net/F8KHF/1/

Comment: I remade the http://jsfiddle.net/F8KHF/3/ from your last specs! Careful, it is not really "bootstrapy", and I do not guarantee the responsiveness (responsivity?).

Comment: Thanks Yoann. I will probably pick up one of your other jsfiddle because the latest does not guarantee responsiveness

Comment: I have some issues using bootstrap. I would like to show the live webpage that is causing the problem,if you can give me an email id, I can forward the login details so that I could explain better.

Answer (score 1):

Add the class form-control to ALL of your input elements for a start:

```
<input type="radio" class='form-control' checked="checked" name="price_order" id="id_price_order_1" value="lowest_price" >
```

Also, what I do to make my life easier is to pre-wrap the elements in the correct sized divs instead of doing it in the labels and inputs like so:

```
<div class='row'>
    <form ... >
        <div class='col-lg-2>
            <label ... ></label>
            <input ... >
        </div>
        <div class='col-lg-2'>
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    </form>
</div>
```

Its a tiny bit slower to load but it makes the code so much more readable I think it is worth it. Also I feel that there is a lot of extra in your code that shouldn't be there and is confusing check out the code here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms. They show you exactly how to format an in-line form.

Could being inside a .jumbotron be causing the issues? Why don't you try a panel or a well This should work for you:

```
<div class='panel panel-default'>
<div class="panel-heading">In-line Form</div>
<div class="panel-body">
    <form action='anotherScript.php' method='post' class='form-inline'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-4'>
            <strong>Price:</strong>
            <div class="radio-inline">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="rad1" value="low" checked>
                    Lowest
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio-inline">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="rad1" value="high">
                        Highest
                    </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-4'>
            <div class="checkbox-inline">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name='date' value='date'>
                    Latest Date
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-md-4'>
            <div class="checkbox-inline">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name='year' value='year'> 
                    Latest Year
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-12'>
            <center><button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Submit</button></center></form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/5046/

Make sure you stretch the results panel to full width to see the form in-line.

Comment: I added `form-control` as you suggested, it still did not fix the issues. please see my edit above

Comment: Thanks for rebuilt code. I am wondering if crispy forms did not have that flexibility to include these, rather than hard coding it in HTML

Comment: It is possible. Whenever I have found sites built with templates rather than being hard coded, their markup has been very scattered and difficult to understand. Coding it yourself always always you to control layout and readability much better.